# How to fit a SARIMAX model to a large dataset? Currently very slow

Tags: time-series, bigdata, forecasting, training-data, predict

I have been trying to fit a SARIMAX() model with a series containing 713488 data points.

It takes a long time to load, even over a few days it won't fit. I believe this is down the quantity of input data?

How could one work around this? Is it worth trying with different parameters, would you recommend using less data? Is there a different algorithm you would recommend?

```
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
mod = SARIMAX(t, trend='c', order=(2,0,3), seasonal_order=(1,0,0,12),
              enforce_stationarity=False, enforce_invertibility=False)
```

Comment: how many rows you got?

Comment: 71 000 good sir